# Consequence of Hahn Banach theorem is the statement correct?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

The theorem B page 227 of this book :Introduction to Topology and Modern Analysis (G. Simmons, 2003) is stated as:

> If $N$ is a normed linear space and $x_0$  is a non-zero vector in
> $N$, then there exists a functional $f_0$ in $N^*$ such that
> $f_0(x_0)=\|x_0\|$ and $\|f_0\|=1$.

I don't understand why we should have $f_0(x_0)=\|x_0\|$ on $N$, is there any mistake ? I would agree if the author would have written $|f_0(x_0)|=\|x_0\|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to make $f_0(x_0)$ non-negative. For example, suppose that we already have $|f_0(x_0)| = ||x_0||$. Choose a suitable $\theta\in \mathbb{C}$ with $|\theta|=1$ such that $|f_0(x_0)| = \theta f_0(x_0)$. (If the scalar field is $\mathbb{R}$, then $\theta=1$ or $\theta = -1$). Define $g = \theta f$. Then $||f||=||g||$ and $g(x_0) = ||x_0||$.